# Binding.scala using UI-Semantics: applyDynamic does not support passing a vararg parameter

Tags: semantic-ui, scala.js, binding.scala

I want to display a tooltip on an element, like:

```
  <div class="ui item"
         data:data-tooltip="Choose the adapter job"
         data:data-position="bottom right">
      <select id="jobConfigSelect"
              class="ui compact dropdown"
              onchange={_: Event =>
                changeSelectedJobConfig(jobConfigSelect.value))}>
        {Constants(jobConfigs.configs.values.map(selJobConfigOption).toSeq: _*)
        .map(_.bind)}
      </select>
    </div>
```

This gives this strange error:
[image]

Without these 2 lines:

```
data:data-tooltip="Choose the adapter job"
data:data-position="bottom right"
```

the code runs perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like [a Scala compiler bug](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/7420) that has been fixed in latest Scala 2.12.

It [compiles in Scala 2.12](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/yXNtdXr/0), and [causes error in Scala 2.11](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/tHNzqNH/0).

Comment: Verified with scala 2.12.5

Answer (score 1):

After some 'trying' I found this solution:

You cannot have the `data:data-tooltip`attribute in the same method as you have a `Constants` construct. So you have to split them:

```
    ...
    <div class="ui item"
         data:data-tooltip="Choose the adapter job"
         data:data-position="bottom right">
      {selJobConfigSelect(jobConfigs).bind}
    </div>
  }

  @dom
  private def selJobConfigSelect(jobConfigs: JobConfigs) = {
    <select id="jobConfigSelect"
            class="ui compact dropdown"
            onchange={_: Event =>
              changeSelectedJobConfig(jobConfigs.fromIdent(s"${jobConfigSelect.value}"))}>
      {Constants(jobConfigs.configs.values.map(selJobConfigOption).toSeq: _*)
      .map(_.bind)}
    </select>
  }
```

What I haven't figured out is: **Why this is?**